# Foreach ou for dentro de um Anynimous Type C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, api

Estou montando um retorno de uma Api em `JSON`, E o retorno eu monto em **AnynimousType** acredito que seja assim que se chama, nele eu nomeio as variáveis conforme irão para o Json, Porém eu precisava fazer um **foreach** para retornar as parcelas, de uma forma de pagamento, como no Exemplo abaixo:

```
//Pega as formas de pagamento do Banco de dados
        var formas = _ctx.FormasPagamento.Where(e => e.DataExclusao == null && e.EmpresaID == 1).ToList();

        //Monta o retorno em JSON usando AnynimousType
        return Json(formas.Select(e => new
        {
            e.Descricao,
            e.DiaAdicional,
            QtdParcelas = e.Parcelas,
            e.PctTaxaFinanceira,
            PrazoMedio = e.FormaPagamentoParcelas.Select(x => x.Prazo).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() / e.Parcelas,
            PerPgDup = e.Parcelas / 100,

            //Aqui neste trecho seria onde eu precisava montar uma lista com as parcelas desta forma de pagamento..
            //Tentei dessa forma mas o codigo nao reconhece a operação
            ParcelasPgto = new
            {
                foreach(var forma in e.FormaPagamentoParcelas) {
                forma.Prazo,
                }
            } 

        }));
```

O código acima não funciona, e seria o que eu precisaria fazer, Fazendo com Models o Json serializa certinho, vou mostrar um Exemplo do retorno que eu precisava porem usando Models, O que eu não queria pois tem que criar classes Extras no projeto sem "Necessidade"..

**CLASSES MODELO:**

```
public class FormaPgto
{
    public FormaPgto()
    {
        ParcelasPgtos = new List<ParcelaPgto>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int DiaAdicional { get; set; }
    public int QtdParcelas { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxaFinanceira { get; set; }
    public int PrazoMedio { get; set; }

    public int PerPgDup { get; set; }

    public List<ParcelaPgto> ParcelasPgtos { get; set; }
}

public class ParcelaPgto
{
    public int Prazo { get; set; }
}
```

**MÉTODO:**

```
 //Pega as formas de pagamento do Banco de dados
        var formas = _ctx.FormasPagamento.Where(e => e.DataExclusao == null && e.EmpresaID == 1).ToList();

        //Aqui é a classe de retorno que eu criei
        var formasRetorno = new List<FormaPgto>();

        //Percorre as formas de pagamento
        foreach (var forma in formas)
        {
            //Mapeia a classe usado como retorno para o Json serializar
            var frm = new FormaPgto();
            frm.Id = forma.ID;
            frm.Descricao = forma.Descricao;
            frm.DiaAdicional = forma.DiaAdicional;
            frm.QtdParcelas = forma.Parcelas;
            frm.TaxaFinanceira = forma.PctTaxaFinanceira;
            frm.PrazoMedio = forma.FormaPagamentoParcelas.Select(x => x.Prazo).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() /
                             forma.Parcelas;
            frm.PerPgDup = forma.Parcelas / 100;

            //Percorre as parcelas da forma de pagamento, como necessitava no outro código
            foreach (var parc in forma.FormaPagamentoParcelas)
            {
                //Instancia a model da parcela
                var pct = new ParcelaPgto();
                //Mepeia
                pct.Prazo = parc.Prazo;
                //Adiciona a uma lista na forma de pagamento
                frm.ParcelasPgtos.Add(pct);
            }
            formasRetorno.Add(frm);
        }

        //Retorna em Json
        return Json(formasRetorno);
```

O metodo acima com as classes me retorno o Json como preciso, conforme modelo abaixo:
[image: Retorno Json Necessario]

Desta forma funciona, porem tem que criar classes de modelo e o trabalho é maior, E mapeando com AninimousType além de dar a liberdade de Definir os nomes das variaveis Json no momento do Retorno, descarta a criação de classes (models) adicionais no proejeto, apenas para usar um retorno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando o `Linq` você pode escrever algo como o exemplo abaixo, para simplificar...

```
ParcelasPgto = e.FormaPagamentoParcelas.Select(fp => new { Prazo = fp.Prazo}).ToList();
```

Comment: Perfeito, Obrigado